# pyqt5 can't detect all my installed themes

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5, themes

I've installed pyqt5 using

```
pip3 install --user pyqt5  
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5  
sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
```

these commands in my mx-linux(de: KDEPlasma).
Now `QStyleFactory.keys()` can't detect my themes there is just `['Windows','Fusion']` while in qt-designer there are much more themes such as(breeze style, bb10dark style, gtk2 style, cleanlook style,...)

How can I add these styles to `QStyleFactory.keys()` and use in my app.

Comment: Your problem is simple: The Qt that QtDesigner uses is different than the Qt that PyQt5 uses. According to what you indicate, I see that you have installed PyQt5 by 2 different means: `pip3 install --user pyqt5` and `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`  and that is always a bad idea since it brings conflicts so you have 2 options: Uninstall the pyqt5 that you installed using pip and reinstalling the one that you installed with apt-get, or compile styles plugins as the duplicate post points out.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, worked like a charm :)